# Is "typename" allowed/required in C++11 using-declaration?

Tags: c++, c++11, typename, using-declaration

The following code compiles correctly in g++ and clang:

```
template<typename T>
struct foo
{
    class iterator;
    using bar = foo::iterator;
};

int main() {}
```

however MSVC 2013 gives the following errors:

```
foo.cpp(9): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'iterator'
          foo.cpp(10) : see reference to class template instantiation 'foo<T>' being compiled
foo.cpp(9): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
```

If I change that line to:

```
using bar = typename foo::iterator;
```

then all three compilers compile it successfully.  Is the original version correct? (i.e. is this a MSVC bug, or a gcc/clang extension)

Comment: Allowed, yes. Required, no. `foo::iterator` names a member of the current instantiation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[temp.res]/p3:

> When a *qualified-id* is intended to refer to a type that is not a
>   member of the current instantiation (14.6.2.1) and its
>   *nested-name-specifier* refers to a dependent type, it shall be prefixed by the keyword `typename`, forming a *typename-specifier*.

[temp.dep.type]/p1:

> A name refers to the *current instantiation* if it is
>
> - in the definition of a class template, a nested class of a class template, a member of a class template, or a member of a nested class
>     of a class template, the injected-class-name (Clause 9) of the class
>     template or nested class,
> - [...]

[temp.dep.type]/p4:

> A name is a *member of the current instantiation* if it is
>
> - An unqualified name that, when looked up, refers to at least one member of a class that is the current instantiation or a non-dependent
>     base class thereof. [ *Note*: This can only occur when looking up a
>     name in a scope enclosed by the definition of a class template. —*end
>     note* ]
> - A *qualified-id* in which the *nested-name-specifier* refers to the current instantiation and that, when looked up, refers to at least one
>     member of a class that is the current instantiation or a non-dependent
>     base class thereof. [ *Note*: if no such member is found, and the
>     current instantiation has any dependent base classes, then the
>     qualified-id is a member of an unknown specialization; see below.
>     —*end note* ]
> - [...]

`foo` is the current instantiation. `foo::iterator` is a *qualified-id* in which the *nested-name-specifier* (`foo::`) refers to the current instantiation, and when looked up, "refers to at least one member of a class that is the current instantiation or a non-dependent base class thereof"; it therefore is a member of the current instantiation. Therefore, [temp.res]/p3 does not apply, and no `typename` is required. You are still allowed to add one - or just use `iterator` unqualified directly.

Comment: I think this does it, you found it faster, +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

From the standard:

> **14.6.2.1 Dependent types** [temp.dep.type]
>
> 1 A name refers to the current instantiation if it is
>
> __ in the definition of a class template, a nested class of a class template, a member of a class template, or a member of a nested class of a class template, the injected-class-name (Clause 9) of the class template
> or nested class,

The name `foo` refers to the current instantiation, that is obvious.

Since `iterator` is declared as a nested class in the definition of the template, `iterator` refers to the name in the current instantiation of `foo`. `foo::iterator` is the same as `iterator`.

```
using bar = foo::iterator;
```

as well as

```
using bar = iterator;
```

should work.

It seems to me that you have run into a MSVC defect.